# Получить центральный пиксель из изображения формата YUV

Tags: java, изображения

Получить центральный пиксель из изображения формата YUV

Как получить цвет пикселя по координатам  x,y?

```
x = width / 2;
y = height / 2;

// Get YUV coordinates  for x y position                        
int YCord     = y;
int UCord     = (int) (total + (y >> 1) * width)+ 1;
int VCord     = (int) (total + (y >> 1) * width);

// Get YUV colors
int Y = (0xFF & imageBytes[YCord]) - 16;
int U = (0xFF & imageBytes[UCord]) - 128;
int V = (0xFF & imageBytes[VCord]) - 128;
```

Как изменить центральный блок что бы это работало верно.

Потому что сейчас оно выдает цвет не из центрального места

**UPDATED**

Изображение в формате YUV просто набор байтов три плоскости Y U V

```
ByteBuffer yBuff = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
ByteBuffer uBuff = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
ByteBuffer vBuff = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
ByteArrayOutputStream  outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] yByte = new byte[yBuff.remaining()];
byte[] uByte = new byte[uBuff.remaining()];
byte[] vByte = new byte[vBuff.remaining()];
yBuff.get(yByte);
uBuff.get(uByte);
vBuff.get(vByte);

// Create converting byte[] NV21
try {
    outputStream.write(yByte);
    for (int i=0; i < uByte.length; i++) {
        outputStream.write(vByte[i]);
        outputStream.write(uByte[i]);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Вот из массива `imageBytes` нужно получить цвет центрального пикселя (я получил цвет но не из центра)

Comment: я не улавливаю как связаны координаты пикселя и формат изображения

Comment: Ок. Есть изображение в формате YUV как из него взять центральный пиксель?

Comment: Я надеюсь речь про `BufferedImage` ?

Comment: добавил код в вопросе

Comment: А нельзя сразу из оригинальных буферов взять? считать меньше придется, Вам для чего-то еще нужен `imageBytes` ?

Comment: Это оригинальные буферы. image приходит из cam2api в формате YUV потому что он самый быстрый

Comment: вы создали 3 байт буффера, по буферу на компонент, берите значения центрального элемента из них

Comment: Спасибо. Но так это не работает

Comment: Это почему, интересно

Comment: ок, может я чего то не понимаю?
я попробовал и даже цвет корректный не собрался из любой точки
+ по структуре изображения 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqqJD.png
это априори не может работать

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/lirugo/screenDetector
я нашел решение если кому интересно по ссылке код а получение пикселя по координатам

```
x = 210; // might be 250
y = height - 215; // might be 150

// Get YUV coordinates  for x y position
int YCord     = y*width+x;
int UCord     = ((y/2)*width+(x&~1)+total+1);
int VCord     = ((y/2)*width+(x&~1)+total);
```